# Is it a bad idea to use DateTime.MinValue / MaxValue in unit tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, date, testing, .net-core

I'm writing some unit tests, which use some objects with date properties that I need to set.

Instead of defining my own hardcoded dates, I've been using DateTime.MinValue and MaxValue.

I've heard unit tests should be deterministic, but the C# docs say that MinValue/MaxValue are static readonly fields and not constants. Would this make my tests nondeterministic? Also I'm wondering if I should just define my own hardcoded dates instead for the tests.

Comment: _"Also I'm wondering if I should just define my own hardcoded dates instead for the tests."_ <-- Yes, do this instead.

Comment: The only reason they're `readonly` and not `const` is that `const` applies only to a small subset of primitive types, and `DateTime` isn't on that list. It's not because `DateTime.MinValue` is going to ever change. That said, `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue` are both extreme values, that may influence the outcome of your tests in ways that wouldn't happen with "normal" values. Good if you're testing for edge cases, not so good if you're not.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that `default(DateTime) == DateTime.MinValue` - while `default(TimeSpan) == TimeSpan.Zero` (and not `TimeSpan.MinValue`), and `default(Int32) == 0` and _not_ `Int32.MinValue` - _le sigh_.

Comment: @Dai: this only seems inconsistent if you fail to consider that .NET's `DateTime` is effectively an unsigned type, while `TimeSpan` and `Int32` are not. `default(UInt32) == UInt32.MinValue`. The default, for *all* types, is "zero", which for unsigned types alone is also `MinValue`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert But that _is surprising_ on the basis that the CLS actively discourages unsigned types: therefore one must assume that most value-types are using some kind of signed-representation internally. `DateTime` is actually quite unusual *because* it's unsigned - which makes me wonder how it works in .NET environments ported to environments without support for unsigned types...

Comment: It really depends on what you test. In some tests for example I'm using `DateTime.UtcNow` or dates that are created based on random values (in a specific range). In other tests I have complete hard-coded dates to examine a specific edge case or similar. So take, what best matches.

Comment: @Dai: The internal representation is effectively irrelevant, only the actual semantics matter. `DateTime` doesn't allow negative values; that was a design choice (not a restriction of the representation) and it's one you can argue with (and there are date/time libraries that do it differently). What kind of types the underlying architecture supports (efficiently) is another matter altogether. The fact of the matter is that the .NET runtime has a notion of unsigned values, whether the CLS discourages it or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values aren't compile-time constants, because they can't be - but they'll never change. Your unit tests are fine in terms of being deterministic.

That said, there are oddities about `DateTime.MinValue` and `DateTime.MaxValue`, in terms of how they'll respond to arithmetic operations (e.g. you can't subtract a day from `DateTime.MinValue`).

That means in at least *some* cases it's useful to have:

- A test case for a "normal" date
- A test case for `DateTime.MinValue`
- A test case for `DateTime.MaxValue`

... just in case your code *ought* to handle extreme values but doesn't for some reason. That said, it really depends on the code you're testing.

Comment: Such arithmetic operations can also unintended happen, when you start using TimeZones  or converting from UTC to local time or similar.

Comment: _" (e.g. you can't subtract a day from `DateTime.MinValue`)."_ - well, to be fair: you can try, but it will only blow up in your face at runtime. Reasons like this are why I can't wait for interval-types to go mainstream.

Comment: @Oliver: Yes indeed - I didn't want to go into too much extra detail without knowing more context.